# Are there limits on the schema size for a BigQuery table?

Tags: google-bigquery

Beyond the per-row limits at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/preparing-data-for-bigquery?hl=en#dataformats (which would likely influence the maximum useful schema), is there an explicit limit on the size of a JSON-encoded table schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a hard limit of 10K fields per table. This, I guess, can indirectly be a limit on schema size

Comment: Note that this is a limit on the number of leaf fields.  `RECORD`s do not count against the field limit.